# If my train is cancelled and replaced, must I take the indicated replacement train when I have a Sparpreis ticket?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

My train is cancelled but replace by a train with the same timetable but a different number; identical to [the scenario in this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/110398/2509).

Under those circumstances, does the *Sparpreis* ticket have *Zugbindung* or not?  Normally, with a *Sparpreis*, the ticket is only valid for the indicated train.  This requirement is lifted when the train is ≥20 minutes delayed or cancelled.  Is the requirement still lifted when a replacement train with the same timetable is available?  Must I travel on the replacement train, or can I now also travel on a train departing at a different time?

Reasons to want to do this could be: other time more convenient, seat reservations possible unavailable, replacement stock may be shorter thus busier, or others.

Comment: I guess the key question if it is a replacement train operating with the same number, or not.

Comment: @o.m. Different number.  Edited for clarification.

Comment: Also [asked on Twitter](https://twitter.com/gerrit_holl/status/1206594817943310336)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, Deutsche Bahn has never given a really official opinion about this, as far as I know.
Semi-official opinions differ:

[You can choose freely](https://web.archive.org/web/20200930223340/https://community.bahn.de/questions/1858383-entfallt-zugbindung-sparpreistickets-ausfall-zuges-ersatzzug-angeboten)

[You need to use the replacement train.](https://community.bahn.de/questions/1627535-ic-ersatz-fur-ice-sparpreisticket)

My personal opinion is that you are allowed to choose freely, but that is only my opinion. I have done just this and I was fine.

In practice it would be best to go to a DB information or travel center in advance and ask them to stamp your ticket with "Zugbindung aufgehoben". If you get the stamp, you are golden.